# How to request specific data from the Google Search Console API using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-search-console

I'm trying to recover Google Discover data from the Google Search Console through its API and display it in a Google Sheet.

I'm following a tutorial that walked me through setting up the needed authentications in the Google Cloud platform and showed me how to set up a basic request that retrieves a list of websites I have access to in the Search Console.

What I don't understand is how to modify the code below so that the API retrieves Google Discover data instead of a list of websites I have access to.

The Google Apps Script code gets the mentioned websites and populates two columns, one with the website link and another with the access level I have for that website.

```
 function listAccountSites() {
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
  
    var apiURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites";
    
    var headers = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken()
    };
    
    var options = {
      "headers": headers,
      "method" : "GET",
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);
    
    var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(json)
    
    var URLs = []
    for (var i in json.siteEntry) {
      URLs.push([json.siteEntry[i].siteUrl, json.siteEntry[i].permissionLevel]); 
    }
    s_sites.getRange(2,1,URLs.length,2).setValues(URLs);
    
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', authorizationUrl);
    Browser.msgBox('Open the following URL and re-run the script: ' + authorizationUrl)
  }
}
```

Using [this](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query) Google documentation page I was able to construct an API request that would get the Google Discover data I need, but as I said I cannot figure out how to do this. The mentioned request gets the data I need is the following one:

```
{
  "startDate": "2021-11-01",
  "endDate": "2021-11-05",
  "dimensions": [
    "PAGE"
  ],
  "type": "DISCOVER"
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what exactly is the problem? It is not clear after reading your question what the problem is or what you need to get working.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Can you show the result of `response.getContentText()`, is retrieving any data? Also, you can check if the response contains what you need [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sites/list#try-it)

Comment: Note that the endpoint you call in your code refers to [this](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sites/list). And if you need to use Search Analytics, the url construction has to be: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3 /sites/siteUrl/searchAnalytics/query`

Comment: I changed the var apiURL to "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/MyWebsite/searchAnalytics/query", and in "var options" changed the `"method" : "GET"` to `"method" : "POST"`. But the log says taht the `startDate` is missing, where exactly do I add it?

Comment: You have to add the object of the query as the request body inside of your options. `body: JSON.parse({...})`

Comment: I placed `"startDate": "2021-11-01", "endDate": "2021-11-05",` in `var options` but the error log still displays the following `{error={code=400, message=startDate field is required., errors=[{reason=required, domain=global, locationType=parameter, location=start_date, message=startDate field is required.}, {reason=required, domain=global, locationType=parameter, location=end_date, message=endDate field is required.}]}}`

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify` insted of `JSON.parse` when making the request. Also try `"payload":JSON.st....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following request using Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query)

  ```
    POST https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F/searchAnalytics/query?key={MY_API_KEY}
    {
      "startDate": "2015-04-01",
      "endDate": "2015-05-01",
      "dimensions": ["country","device"]
    }
  ```
- In your situation, you want to use the following request body.

  ```
    {
      "startDate": "2021-11-01",
      "endDate": "2021-11-05",
      "dimensions": [
        "PAGE"
      ],
      "type": "DISCOVER"
    }
  ```

If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

This sample script supposes that your access token can be used and you have already been able to use the API. Please be careful this.

```js
var siteUrl = "https://www.example.com/"; // Please set the site URL.

var apiURL = `https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/${encodeURIComponent(siteUrl)}/searchAnalytics/query`;
var headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken() };
var payload = {
  "startDate": "2021-11-01",
  "endDate": "2021-11-05",
  "dimensions": ["PAGE"],
  "type": "DISCOVER"
};
var options = {
  "headers": headers,
  "method": "POST",
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);
```

#### References:

- [Search Analytics: query](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: I think that is exactly what I need, but when I implement the code this error show up "The range must contain at least one line." for this line of code `s_sites.getRange(2,1,URLs.length,2).setValues(URLs);`

Comment: A friend helped me resolve the final error. The `for` code was changed to `for (var i in json.rows) { s_sites.appendRow([json.rows[i].keys[0], json.rows[i].clicks]); }` and now everything works like a charm.

Comment: @Gilbert Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.